# Google maps, display mysql information in marker info window

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have two mysql tables: "cars" and "locations".

Cars are assigned to a locations by having field "location_id" in "cars" table. I am showing locations in a google maps retrieving coordinates from "locations" table.

What I would like to do, is to show in info window of google maps marker (which mark a location) which cars are assigned to this location.

I use get_locations.php with this code to retrieve information from DB:

```
  $query_cars = "SELECT * FROM cars where location_lat not like ''";
  $cars = $db->query($query_cars);
  $row_cars = $cars->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  $query_locations = "SELECT id, name, gpslat, gpslong FROM locations where name not like '%/ Zona%' and status='Activa'";
  $locations = $db->query($query_locations);
  $rowLocations = $locations->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  echo json_encode($rowLocations);
```

Than I call this script from html page with this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />

    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map-canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API KEY">
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function makeRequest(url, callback) {
        var request;
          if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
              request = new XMLHttpRequest(); // IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          } else {
              request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); // IE6, IE5
          }
          request.onreadystatechange = function() {
              if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
                  callback(request);
              }
          }
        request.open("GET", url, true);
        request.send();
      }

      var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.430013, -3.695854),
          zoom: 12
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
            mapOptions);

        makeRequest('get_locations.php', function(data) {
            var data = JSON.parse(data.responseText);         
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
              displayLocation(data[i]);
            }
        });

        var image = 'http://www.bluemove.es/equipo/images/car_location_Normal.png';

        function displayLocation(location) {
          var content = '<div class="infoWindow">' + location.name; // content of the pop up window
          if (parseInt(location.gpslat) == 0) {
              geocoder.geocode( { 'address': location.address }, function(results, status) {
                  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

                      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                          map: map, 
                          position: results[0].geometry.location,
                          title: location.name,
                          incon: image
                      });

                      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                          infowindow.setContent(content);
                          infowindow.open(map,marker);
                      });
                  }
              });
          } else {
              var position = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(location.gpslat), parseFloat(location.gpslong));
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  map: map, 
                  position: position,
                  title: location.name,
                  icon: image
              });

              google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                  infowindow.setContent(content);
                  infowindow.open(map,marker);
              });
          }
        }
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"/>
  </body>

</html>
```

So when marker is clicked, the location name is displayed on the info window. But as I said I also want to display car name that are assigned to this location.

Does anybody have any idea?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have to make an INNER JOIN query so the $rowLocations will contain both table values.

Something like that:

```
SELECT * FROM cars AS c INNER JOIN locations AS l ON c.cars = l.location_id 
WHERE c.location_lat NOT LIKE "'" AND l.name NOT LIKE '%/ Zona%';
```

Comment: Thank you for your advise. I forgot to mention that there are more than one car assigned to every location. Do you think if it can cause the problem using Inner join?

Comment: The INNER JOIN will return as many rows as the cars connected with one location. In that case a special code manipulation needed to serialize the data (cars) to appear in one infowindow. I believe this is what you want to do, if I understood your request.

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite new to Google Maps API but while doing some research the other day I saw this.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple

Is it as easy as putting php into that `contentString`